# Obtaining GPS coordinates from Openstreet map and integrate them in an application

Tags: node.js, gps, openstreetmap

I have to create a battery analytics application for the car but I don't have real data avilable so I have created an online data generator. This generator (writen in node.js) generates different data for the car battery,speed, position etc. Regarding the position,I want to obtain GPS coordinates (from Openstreetmap) for different paths and integrate them in my generator.Can you suggest me any solution how this can be done?

Comment: This is a very unspecific question. What kind of paths? For routing with OSM take a look at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers.

Comment: With path I mean coordinates of a road. lets say the coordinates of a road which connects 2 cities. So, if the car goes from city 1 to city 2, I want to retrieve all the coordinates (latitude and longitude) for all this move.

Comment: In that case I already answered your question. Take a look at the list of online routers for OSM. Several of them offer route exports as GPX or other formats.